# Basic Drag and Drop uitableview Cell in another view

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop

I just want to tableview drag in any uiview then call one web services.
Please help me out. And if it's possible I'd like to enable the drag by a long press on tableview.

```
in table view
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:cell action:nil];
        longPress.delegate = self;
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];



- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    if([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]){
        [gestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(longGestureAction:)];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}

-(void)longGestureAction:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    UITableViewCell *cell= (UITableViewCell *)[gesture view];

   }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Stackoverflow is designed to help you with a specific *problem*, not with developing an application for you.

Comment: just give me basic solution where should i start, what should i user

Comment: UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:cell action:nil];
        longPress.delegate = self;
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

Comment: There is a tutorial [here](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/tutorial/ios-5-drag-and-drop-between-uitableviews/) which demonstrate dragging from cell in one tableview to another tableview. It looks like it offers something similar to what you want to achieve here.